# How to make my exception handling mechansim resumptive?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> vector_int;
//My pop exception class!
class cPopOnEnpty{};
//My push exception class!
class cPushOnFull{};

class cStack
{
private:
    vector_int v;
    int m_top, m_cap;
public:
    cStack(int capacity):m_top(0),m_cap(capacity){}
    void pop()
    {
        if(m_top==0)
            throw cPopOnEnpty();
        v.erase(v.begin()+m_top);
        m_top--;
    }
    void push(int const& i)
    {
        if(m_top==m_cap)
            throw cPushOnFull();
        v.push_back(i); m_top++;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cStack c(3);
    try {
        c.pop(); //m_top = 0 So exception should be thrown!
        c.push(2); //m_top = 1
        c.push(10); //m_top =2
        c.push(3);  //m_top =3
        c.push(19); //m_top = 4 Exception should be thrown here!
    }
    catch (cPopOnEnpty&)
    {
        std::cerr<< "Caught: Stack empty!"<<std::endl;
    }
    catch(cPushOnFull&)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Caught: Stack full!"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O/P -
Caught: Stack empty!

Desired O/P - 
Caught: Stack empty!
Caught: Stack full!

In the code above I am handling a pop on empty vector and a push on full(capacity is restricted by me) vector. These case I am not getting my desired o/p as the control reaches end of main and the program exits. How can I make this resumptive so that after handling the exception for one call it goes to the next call?

Here the next statements after `c.pop()` should be executed. Need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a Try/Catch block for each method call.

```
try
{
    c.pop(); //m_top = 0 So exception should be thrown!
}
catch(cPopOnEnpty&)
{
    std::cerr<< "Caught: Stack empty!"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: As ugly as it is, this is the only way C++ allows.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow to resume after an exception since the stack has already been unwound (unlike eg. Lisp's conditions which are a totally different beast).

You will have to architecture your code some other way, for example like @RobertHarvey suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        c.pop(); //m_top = 0 So exception should be thrown!
    }
    catch (cPopOnEnpty&)
        {
            std::cerr<< "Caught: Stack empty!"<<std::endl;
        }
    try{
        c.push(2); //m_top = 1
        c.push(10); //m_top =2
        c.push(3);  //m_top =3
        c.push(19); //m_top = 4 Exception should be thrown here!
    }
    catch(cPushOnFull&)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Caught: Stack full!"<<std::endl;
    }
```

Problem solved! Thank you guys! :D